# How do I Scrape my own data from my bank's website using R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

So my bank (in South Africa) allows me to log in and download my own transactional data in a csv format. I would like to automate this process using some kind of scraper in R. The problem is the website is password protected. How can this be done?

Comment: You can either look into Selenium, or learn about POST requests, sessions, cookies, etc. I'd recommend using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck using the `rvest` library. Your bank's cybersecurity may however require 2FA or something else that *intentionally* cannot be accessed via a web scraper. Below is some very generic sample code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://"
session <- html_session(url)              
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]

filled_form <- set_values(form,`[login]` = "xxx",`[password]` = "xxx")

session <- submit_form(session,filled_form)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but to little avail. I do wish I could enter the bank's website address. Perhaps the answers would be more specific.